# How to change firebase project after configure a project before

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, deployment, hosting

First of all, you have to go to your vs code where your code files are available then follow those steps...

1. Delete the 'firebase.json' file
2. Delete the '.firebaseerc'
3. Delete the 'build' folder if you build your project before.
   After 3 steps again follow the firebase hosting steps. Those steps are worked for my project

Comment: The body of your question reads more like an answer than a question. Do you still have this question?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the 'firebase.json' file.
Delete the '.firebaseerc'
Delete the 'build' folder if you build your project before. After 3 steps again follow the firebase hosting steps. Those steps are worked for my project.